# How to add multi-line label on a Java GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jlabel

I have made a java swing GUI. Now I want to display a static message on that but the message is multi-line and the JLabel is single line.

How can I display that message?

Is there any property of JLabel which we can set to display the multiple line message?

Will I have to use several JLabels for multiple lines?

Is there any other way I can display that message?

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090098/newline-in-jlabel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)

[Displaying Multi Line Text](http://java.sun.com/developer/JDCTechTips/2002/tt0723.html#tip2)

Answer (score 7):

You can do

```
JLabel l = new JLabel("<html><p>Hello World! blah blah blah</p></html>");
```

and it will automatically wrap it where appropriate.