# make a JLabel wrap it's text by setting a max width

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jlabel

I have a JLabel which has a lot of text on it. Is there a way to make the JLabel have a max width so that it will wrap the text to make it not exceed this width?

Thanks

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627048/how-to-add-multi-line-label-on-a-java-gui

Answer (score 65, accepted):

No.

You can use HTML in the label, but then you must hard code the break tag.

A better approach is to use a JTextArea and turn wrapping on. You can change the background,foreground, font etc. of the text are to make it look like a label.

**Note, this answer is outdated as of at least Java 7.**

As per @darren's answer, you simply need to wrap the string with `<html>` and `</html>` tags:

```
myLabel.setText("<html>"+ myString +"</html>");
```

You do not need to hard-code any break tags.  The text wraps as the component resizes.

Comment: That's not entirely true. If using HTML you *can* hard code the break tags, but if you use HTML and assign the maximum size, the text will get wrapped automatically.

Comment: If you decide to hard code break tags, make sure you use <br> and not <br />, as Java 5 doesn't like the latter.

Comment: i like the second idea because the first may break a word to half and what i want is word wrapping

Comment: *"You can use HTML in the label, but then you must hard code the break tag."* This is wrong. CSS can specify a preferred width, then the string will wrap on word, automatically, into as many lines as needed.

Answer (score 50):

Yes there are two similar ways (first with css style="width:...px", second with html WIDTH=.......:

1.

```
labelText = String.format("<html><div style=\"width:%dpx;\">%s</div></html>", width, text);
```

2.

```
labelText = String.format("<html><div WIDTH=%d>%s</div></html>", width, text);
```

Comment: The whole thing about using html to make text wrap feels like a hack, but it's the easiest way to make it work.

Setting the size in the div is exactly what I needed to make the JLabel wrap with a maximum width without any 3rd party libraries or overly-complicated hacks.

Comment: What if window size changes? Text has to be reflown according to new label width, but with this solution you would have to set it again.

Comment: `</html>` btw :)

Answer (score 38):

or simply use

```
myLabel.setText("<html>"+ myString +"</html>");
```

Comment: With JDK 7 that was sufficient, thanks!

`JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel("<html>My very very very long title text</html>");`

Comment: If you do this, you should make sure any HTML entities in `myString` are first escaped. If `myString` is something like "Value < 5" it will appear as "Value 5".

Answer (score 13):

You can use HTML without hard coding break tags if you use paragraph tags instead.

```
JLabel biglabel = new JLabel("<html><p>A lot of text to be wrapped</p></html>");
```

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me. p-tags following a heading, and text isn't wrapped. I do have horizontal scrolling disabled so maybe that's got something to do with it.

Comment: You don't need the p tags.

Answer (score 11):

JXLabel in the [SwingX project](http://swingx.java.net) supports wrapping

```
JXLabel label = new JXLabel(somelongtext);
label.setLineWrap(true);
```

Answer (score 9):

Other than wrapping the text in `<html>` tags, you also have to put the label into a container that respects the preferred height and sets the width to maximum. For example, you can put the label in to the NORTH of a `BorderLayout`.

Here is a simple but complete working program to illustrate this. You can resize the frame in any way you want; the label will occupy the whole width and the height will adjust accordingly to wrap the text. Notice that all that I'm doing is using `<html>` tags and putting the label in the NORTH of the `BorderLayout`.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class LabelWrap {

    public static JPanel createPanel() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("<html>"
            + "<h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h3>"
            + "<p>Duis a tincidunt urna. Phasellus tristique interdum mauris, "
            + "ut vestibulum purus suscipit eget. Aenean massa elit, accumsan "
            + "non faucibus vel, dictum placerat urna. In bibendum est sagittis "
            + "urna iaculis quis sagittis velit commodo. Cum sociis natoque "
            + "penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus "
            + "mus. Nam quis lacus mauris. Phasellus sem libero, convallis "
            + "mattis sagittis vel, auctor eget ipsum. Vivamus molestie semper "
            + "adipiscing. In ac neque quis elit suscipit pharetra. Nulla at "
            + "orci a tortor consequat consequat vitae sit amet elit. Praesent "
            + "commodo lacus a magna mattis vehicula. Curabitur a hendrerit "
            + "risus. Aliquam accumsan lorem quis orci lobortis malesuada.</p>"
            + "<p>Proin quis viverra ligula. Donec pulvinar, dui id facilisis "
            + "vulputate, purus justo laoreet augue, a feugiat sapien dolor ut "
            + "nisi. Sed semper augue ac felis ultrices a rutrum dui suscipit. "
            + "Praesent et mauris non tellus gravida mollis. In hac habitasse "
            + "platea dictumst. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci "
            + "luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vestibulum mattis, "
            + "tortor sed scelerisque laoreet, tellus neque consectetur lacus, "
            + "eget ultrices arcu mi sit amet arcu. Nam gravida, nulla interdum "
            + "interdum gravida, elit velit malesuada arcu, nec aliquam lectus "
            + "velit ut turpis. Praesent pretium magna in nibh hendrerit et "
            + "elementum tellus viverra. Praesent eu ante diam. Proin risus "
            + "eros, dapibus at eleifend sit amet, blandit eget purus. "
            + "Pellentesque eu mollis orci. Sed venenatis diam a nisl tempor "
            + "congue.</p>"
            + "</html>");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        return panel;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() { 
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setContentPane(createPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

There's a good technique [here](http://blog.nobel-joergensen.com/2009/01/18/changing-preferred-size-of-a-html-jlabel/), scroll to the end of the article.

```
JLabel labelBeingUsed = myLabel;
View view = (View) labelBeingUsed.getClientProperty(BasicHTML.propertyKey);
view.setSize(scrollPane1.getWidth(), 0.0f);
float w = view.getPreferredSpan(View.X_AXIS);
float h = view.getPreferredSpan(View.Y_AXIS);
labelBeingUsed.setSize((int) w, (int) h);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me perfectly. Not exactly text-wrapping, but it centers the text. Based on the answers here, I used `align` attribute and set `center`. [More about `align` tag here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-p-align-attribute/)

```java
label.setText("<html><p align=\"center\">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></html>")
```

[screenshot from my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcxHV.png)
(I can't post images yet. Sorry. Hope this helps.)

Answer (score 0):

`<html>` wrapping works but not in all cases. If the parent container uses FlowLayout then it'll not work. Therefore I set it to BoxLayout. Look at this code snippet:

```
javax.swing.JPanel pRefundNote = new javax.swing.JPanel(); 
javax.swing.JLabel lbNote = new javax.swing.JLabel();

pRefundNote.setAlignmentX(0.0F); 
pRefundNote.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(32767, 33)); 
pRefundNote.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(pRefundNote, javax.swing.BoxLayout.X_AXIS)); 

lbNote.setText("<html>Select items using Shift or Ctrl and Up/Down keys or Mouse</html>"); 
lbNote.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.TOP);
lbNote.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.TOP); 
pRefundNote.add(lbNote);
```

Don't add `<br>` because it'll break your text even if you enlarge your parent frame and pRefundNote container.

Answer (score -7):

If you only want to use JLabel than you can try this approach,

just display the number of characters you want to display on label using substring method.

```
public void setLabel(String label){
    String dispLabel=label.substring(0, numOfCharacter);
    labelComponent.setText(dispLabel);
}
```

Comment: This is not text wrapping.