# JLabel doesn't show a long paragraph

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

[image: String Text]

[image: Window]

How can I enable the JLabel to show the whole paragraph?

Comment: try this [jlabel wrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420742/make-a-jlabel-wrap-its-text-by-setting-a-max-width)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>"+test+"</html>");
```

Answer (score 5):

The `JLabel` component is usually used for short pieces of text. If you need to throw in large amounts of texts, you should use the `JTextArea`. Once you use that, you can then wrap the text using the [setLineWrap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setLineWrap%28boolean%29):

> Sets the line-wrapping policy of the text area. If set to true the
>   lines will be wrapped if they are too long to fit within the allocated
>   width.

If you still want to go ahead with the usage of a JLabel (not recommended), setting the size of the label should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 3):

Put the text in html tags and use br-tags to break the line. Nearly every Swing component does support html text.

E.G.:

```
"<html>" + "a line" + "<br />" + 
"second line" + "</html>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to surround the whole string with an HTML p tag as follows:

```
String text = "<html><p>This program........ BIG LINE_HERE....called person.txt</p></html>";
JLabel info = new JLabel(text);
```