# Java Swing: Vertical Layout with fixed width and variable height

Tags: java, swing, layout, vertical-alignment, fixed-width

I'm looking for a layout manager (or set of layout managers) that help me to arrange my components vertically. All components (buttons) should have the same width, bordered by the underlaying dialog client area width. Each of these buttons is able to expand its height depending on the connected JLabel (the labels will be displayed once the user clicked on the related button) - in short: all the components should be stretched to the same fixed width, but with a variable height depending on their content. The whole dialog content should be placed within a JScrollPane to support a vertical scrollbar if needed.

I'm at the point, where I stacked a lot of different layout managers (mostly borderlayout for horizontal stretching and boxlayout for vertical arrangement) to implement my aimed behaviour.
But it's neither satisfying code nor does it work completely as I want.

I spent a lot of time surfing the internet for this problem and discovered that vertical layouts are a common problem in Java. A lot of people replied that GridBagLayout would be the best layout doing this job, but I didn't get it to work the way I wanted.

I hope that is enough information to give me some help for that problem.

Best regards
Michael

edit: -not needed anymore-

edit 2:

Here is an image of my current attempt:
http://www.pic-upload.de/view-16978954/example-image.png.html

This is almost the result i want, but has strange beviour on resizing.

edit 3:

I think my main problem is the JScrollPane combined with a html containing JLabel, I need something like setMaximumSize(...), but it doesn't work as it should:
http://www.pic-upload.de/view-16988005/example-image3.png.html

I need a fixed width, but i cannot find a way to set it.

setPreferredSize(...) works, but I don't know the height of the JLabel, because it contains html text.

edit 4:

my Button:

```
public class Expander extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static class HtmlViewer extends JLabel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8787130155299083869L;


        public HtmlViewer(String doc) {
            super(doc);
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            this.setOpaque(true);
        }
    }


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4480221797736558685L;


    JToggleButton button;
    JComponent component;


    public Expander(String text, String doc) {
        this(text, new HtmlViewer(doc));
    }

    public Expander(String text, JComponent expandableComponent) {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        button = new JToggleButton(text) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -3330376265192275758L;

            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);

                if (this.isSelected()) {
                    g.drawString("▼", this.getWidth() - 20, 15);
                } else {
                    g.drawString("■", this.getWidth() - 20, 15);
                }
            }
        };

        button.setFocusPainted(false);
        button.addActionListener(this);

        component = expandableComponent;
        component.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        this.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (button.isSelected()) {
            this.add(component);
        } else {
            this.remove(component);
        }
        this.getTopLevelAncestor().validate();
        this.getTopLevelAncestor().repaint();
        this.setMaximumSize(this.getPreferredSize());
    }
}
```

the frame:

```
public class grid2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(p, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        addStuff(p);

        frame.add(scroll);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void addStuff(Container container) {
        container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 0;

        Expander e = new Expander("test", "<html>fgb fdh fgfhg ifghiufdshfidsghfiufdsghiudsfhdsfiu dshiufhds if dhf idsufhdsiufhiufhiuds hfdshfiudshfuidsifudshfiudshf  ufdhfiushdfiudshiufhdsiufhdsiuf udshfiudshfiudshfudshf iuhfiudshfiudshfiudshf</html>"); // long html text example
        e.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 10000));
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        container.add(e, c);

        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        container.add(button2, c);

        c.gridy = 2;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        container.add(new JLabel(), c);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be easier if you post a code sample with these buttons and labels.

Comment: I could post one or two images as the result should look like, but I don't know the correct markdown for posting images. :/

Comment: added an image link, I hope this is also OK

Comment: Impossible.  The resizing behavior of the JScrollPane fights with the resizing behavior of the Box layout and the GridBagLayout.

Comment: Take a look at `VerticalLayout` from [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net/)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I already noticed this, that's why I'm looking for an alternative way implementing this.

Comment: @FrecherxDachs: When you (or someone else) finds an alternate way, be sure to test the resizing lots of times.  I almost had something working with nested BoxLayouts, but the layouts quit resizing after a couple of dozen JFrame resizings.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: If I knew Apache Pivot better, I'd try to implement this with Pivot.

Comment: @FrecherxDachs FYI: to make your code look like code with syntax highlighting, dont use tags such as `<code>` but select your code and use the button `{}` in the toolbar of the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it to work. I was completely wrong, I thought the JScrollPane was the trouble maker for this issue, but it was the JLabel. If a JLabel contains HTML text, it won't wrap the text automatically, that's why everything got stretched horizontally, if the dialog's width was too little. I found a good solution for this problem here: [make a JLabel wrap it's text by setting a max width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420742/make-a-jlabel-wrap-its-text-by-setting-a-max-width)

Answer 6:

```
JLabel labelBeingUsed = myLabel;
View view = (View) labelBeingUsed.getClientProperty(BasicHTML.propertyKey);
view.setSize(scrollPane1.getWidth(), 0.0f);
float w = view.getPreferredSpan(View.X_AXIS);
float h = view.getPreferredSpan(View.Y_AXIS);
labelBeingUsed.setSize((int) w, (int) h);
```

Everytime the dialog is resized, it is necessary to update the width of each HTML containing JLabel to the desired width using the code above.

Thank you very much for all your useful tips.

Answer (score 3):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

```
setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you, I know these samples and as I said in the first post, that is way my current code looks like, but box layouts have some crazy stretch behaviours.

Comment: Here is an image of the current result, but has some strange behaviour when the size is resized.

http://www.pic-upload.de/view-16978954/example-image.png.html

Comment: Try setting the preferred size of the buttons

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati No don't setPreferredSize on any component. This is really a bad advice. Setting preferred size prevents taking care of different L&F, different fonts, etc... In almost all case (at least with basic Swing widgets) you should not need to force the preferred size. Leave that to LayoutManagers and XxxUI.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Thanks for letting me know this. Didn't heard this before.

Answer (score 2):

What I would use is a [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).  It is akin to an HTML table, and by using [GridBagConstraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html) you can set the objects to expand in both the horizontal and vertical direction (ex. `constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH`)

I believe this fixes your issue with in the picture below (there is a small hack to make it the buttons stay on the top by adding a blank label at the bottom, but I'm sure that with more tinkering this can be removed)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    addStuff(frame.getContentPane());

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void addStuff(Container container) {
    container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 0;

    JButton button = new JButton("Button 1");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    container.add(button, c);

    JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
    c.gridy = 1;
    container.add(button2, c);

    c.gridy = 2;
    c.weighty = 1;
    container.add(new JLabel(), c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this and the arrangement wasn't right.

Example follows.

Comment: Can you provide an image of what isn't right about the layout.  In the past it has been my experience that with enough tweaking you can get the GridBag to do pretty much whatever you need

Comment: @FrecherxDachs You add a "fill" control to the last position with a `weighty` of 1, this will push the other components to the top of the container.  I normally use a `JPanel` or if I want the container to support transparency, a `JLabel` with no text

Comment: I tried your example, it looks good. But I finally ended up with the same problem as my current solution: I put the whole GridBagLayout in a ScrollPane to enable vertical scrolling if needed, but I used JLabels (containing html information), that doesn't wrap on the right side of the Dialog, so the GridBagLayout will be stretched horizontally. So is there a way saying the GridBagLayout (or the scroll pane viewport) what is the maximum width (should be the same like the dialog width)?

Comment: You should be able to [set the maximum size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setMaximumSize(java.awt.Dimension)) of the Component you are applying the layout to.

Comment: I can set it, but it will be ignored completely.

Comment: I don't know, I expect it's because of the JScrollPane

Answer (score 1):

Several issues here:

1. the `BorderLayout` of the `JFrame` will stretch your `JPanel p`
2. you don't set `weightx`, therefore the `fill` attribute is useless

Solutions:

1. Either wrap your `JPanel p` in another panel that will put it at the top, either add an extra invisible JPanel at the end to push your component
2. set the `weightx` property to `1.0`

Here is a demo code (based on yours) which works:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Gridbag {

    public void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        JButton button = new JButton("button 1");
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        constraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        constraints.weightx = 1.0;
        p.add(button, constraints);

        button = new JButton("button 2");
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        p.add(button, constraints);
        JPanel root = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        constraints.weighty = 1.0;
        root.add(p, constraints);
        frame.add(root);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Gridbag().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, same here, basically works as I want, but if I place it within a JScrollPane the labels will stretch it horizontally, so I need to set my preferred width, but not the height. setMaximumSize doesn't seem to work as expected with a JScrollPane. Some ideas?

Comment: @FrecherxDachs You should not need to set preferredSize/maximumSize/etc... (you should almost never set them actually). If I add a JScrollPane, I don't have any issues. Vertical scrollbar appears when frame height is too small. Post another question with your updated code if it does not work. Remember,

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think my topic is correct, the problem is that the width of the scroll pane viewport is sometimes bigger than the width of the underlaying dialog (because of the content). Do you see my problem? Here again the current behaviour: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-16988005/example-image3.png.html

Comment: @FrecherxDachs update you code with your JScrollPane and the textfield shown on your picture that I don't see in your code.