# JLabel Width dependent from Text Length

Tags: java, resize, jlabel

So I have a `JLabel` here that's text is set from a String taken from a file seen here:

```
Label lName = new JLabel("Charater Name:    " + data[FileIO.NAME]);
        lName.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lName.setBounds(640 - 110, 5, 110, 30);
        add(lName);
```

Since the name could be 3 letters long to 24 letters long I don't want to use a fixed width, I want the label's width to wrap around the text enough so that the text isn't cut off but so that it's not wasting a bunch of space, how can I do this?

Edit:
The JLabel's location will be set programmatically depending on it's width.

Currently my only solution is setting the width to this:
`(int) (lName.getText().length() * (double) 6.8)`
Which lasts for around 40 letters before being cut off.

Comment: I don't know whether you mean the same, but this link provides a similar solution. Try having a look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420742/make-a-jlabel-wrap-its-text-by-setting-a-max-width

Comment: I looked at this before and tried it but it doesn't do what I want.

Comment: Ok. I guess there must be some way to do it. Will let you know if I find any!