# JLabel Text is Cut Off by New Line

Tags: java, html, swing, jpanel, jlabel

Ok, so I was trying out the newline strategy for JLabels([Newline in JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090098/newline-in-jlabel)) by using HTML tags and the `<br>` tag, in a JList with a custom cell renderer, but after the break the text is cut off. I'm not sure how to solve this.
[image: JLabel covered]

```
    private static class RanksListCellRenderer extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer<Rank> {

    private JLabel text = new JLabel();

    public RanksListCellRenderer() {
        super(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        setOpaque(false);
        add(text);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Rank> list,
            Rank value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if (!isSelected) {
            text.setText(value.getRankName());
        } else {
            text.setText("<html>" + value.getRankName() + "<br> Rank Data:</html>");
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I'm guessing I can't post it here, so in a new question then? It seems like a great idea, I'll get to it tomorrow probably, have to do physics tonight.

Comment: It is possible to [edit your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18939661/edit).  See the little line below the tags? `share | edit | delete` (or something like that, depending on rep. and question ownership)