# How to move next line in Label?

Tags: java, swt

I have Label in SWT
The text is

```
     "Doctor\ntest\ttest2"
```

I want to change it to

```
       "Doctor
       test     test2"
```

menaing to change the \n to new line and \t to tab.
Can I do it in Label in SWT? Do I need to change the control ?

Comment: Using different labels for each of the words is a good option...

Comment: See this one.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090098/newline-in-jlabel

Comment: @nobalG OP isn't using Swing/AWT, but SWT.

Comment: @Baz oops,I misinterperated.....thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in the label control.

```
final Label label = new Label(composite, SWT.NULL );
label.setText( "Line one \n line two  abc \t tabbed" );
label.pack();
```

Results in:
[image]

You can also do this by using a Text-Control and set it disabled.