# How to make another line in JLabel

Tags: java, user-interface

hello I know this was dumb question but may I ask how to make another line in JLabel ? Or to make the label Doraemon print on the second line? Thank you in advanced

[image: MY CODES]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then update your question to be a valid question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Newline in JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090098/newline-in-jlabel)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
JLabel l = new JLabel("<html>pikachu<br>Doraemon </html>", SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but there's nothings changes happened in the output :( I tried what you have said

Comment: Please refer to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090098/newline-in-jlabel

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of the Layout Managers, or if you set the layout manager to null by writing

```
fr.setLayout(null);
```

then you should set the bounds correctly

```
lbl.setBounds( , , , ,)
```

and set the paramaters on how far from the top each label should be

the first paramater sets how far from the left and the second from the top. The last 2 set the size of the label.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your code like this `fr.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));`